# Let $l(v)=\int_{\Omega}v\,dx.$ Then $l$ is a continuous linear functional on $H^1(\Omega).$ Then $A=l^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $\Omega$ is connected. Let $$A :=\{v\in H^1(\Omega)\,:\,(v,1)=0 \} $$
where $$(v,w)=\int_{\Omega}vw\,dx,\;\;\;\forall v,w\in H^1(\Omega).$$
Let $l(v)=\int_{\Omega}v\,dx.$ Then $l$ is a continuous linear functional on $H^1(\Omega).$ Then $A=l^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed in $H^1(\Omega)$.

$\textbf{Question}:$
How I can find the $l^{-1}$?   Basically can anyone give me a reference for this theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition,
$$l^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{v\in H^1(\Omega)\,:\, l(v) = 0 \}$$
makes sense even if the inverse function $l^{-1}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of $l^{-1}$ as a inverse function to $l$ then such function does not exist since $l$ is not a bijection.